# Visual C++ run times error

Tags: visual-c++

All case run in Visual C++ 2005 environment

Function definition:

```
char *PQgetvalue(const PGresult *res, int tup_num, int field_num);
```

**Case 1.**

```
CString dd;
dd=(LPCTSTR) PQgetvalue(res,i,0);
```

when above is compiled with NO ERROR but `dd` has store garbage data like: `〱〰71〱1 몭몭몭몭몭몭ꮫꮫꮫꮫ`

**Case 2.**

```
CString dd;
dd= PQgetvalue(res,i,0);
```

No Compilation error and provide correct output.

Question: How to convert `Char*` to `CString`

**Case 3.**

```
CString dd;
dd= PQgetvalue(res,i,0);

CString dd = PQgetvalue(res,i,0);
```

There is NO Difference between above code. But second case generate compilation error like:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' :
cannot convert from 'char *' to 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>'
```

Please clarify anyone

Comment: in case 3 you declare variable named dd twice. is it just here on SO or this is the case  (i.e. 3 lines) with error?

Comment: The difference is the cast in case 1. You are telling the compiler you know better than it does. The error message should tell you what is wrong. You cannot use a char pointer to initialize a CString; you need a wchar_t pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case. I guess you compile your project with Unicode character set (to verify open project settings dialog "Configuration properties" - "General" - "Character set"). Thus converting char* to const wchar_t* would gives you garbage. I.e. TCHAR is wchar_t when you compile with Unicode.

On the C2440. Please clarify whether code in Case 3 is correct (i.e. you supply all 3 lines to compiler as provided here.). Also I'd suggest you to search MSDN on this error.